# How does this way to check two types are of same type work?

Tags: typescript

The `Equal` type define is as below

```
type Equal<X, Y> = (<T>() => T extends X ? 1 : 2) 
  extends <T>() => T extends Y ? 1 : 2
  ? true
  : false;
```

I've tried to write code like:

```
type Foo<X> = <T>() => T extends X ? 1 : 2;
var a: Foo<number> = true;
var b: Foo<boolean> = true;
var c: Foo<any> = true;
var d: Foo<number> = 42;
var e: Foo<boolean> = 42;
var f: Foo<any> = 42;
var g: Foo<number> = () => true;
var h: Foo<boolean> = () => true;
var i: Foo<any> = () => true;
var j: Foo<number> = () => 42;
var k: Foo<boolean> = () => 42;
var l: Foo<any> = () => 42;
```

but none of them is correct

How does this work?

Comment: `Equal` expects two arguments, not one.